# I want to export all the customers who buy between two dates

Tags: magento2

I know how to export my customers, but is it also possible to export my customers who buy between two dates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please go to your admin panel and select export in this **Path:** Sales > Orders

But you can't get the unique customer list you need to sort it using MSExcel or Libre Office.

**Instructions:**

1. Choose the date filter from and to.
2. Apply the filter in the sales order grid and you can see the order reports.
3. Now you can export the orders as CSV, Excel XML.

If you are having difficulties you also can use any extension if the feature is availabe.

[image]

Thank You.

Comment: That's smart! Thanks for this.